# Work with binding within controller of component

Tags: angularjs, binding, components

I've built my own angular component, which a can implement in my code by using it's individual html-tag. So I've got something like this:

**Template:**

```
<div class="myComponent">
    <div ng-transclude></div>
    <span>{{ currentValue }}</span>
</div>
```

As you can see, there I got a span which shows the value of a binding from my controller.

**In my controller**, I implemented the binding like this:

```
static componentOptions = {
    transclude: true,
    bindings: {
        currentValue: "="
    }
}
```

Than I can implement my component in my web-application and give to the binding a value like this:

```
<my-component current-value="myVariable">
    <input ng-model="myVariable">
</my-component>
```

Than I got the result from my binding (for example the text "hello world"). Now I would like to change the value in my controller where the binding is. And because of the `"="` in my binding, it is watched and changes it in my controller and also the parent where it comes from throught the binding. I tried it like this (in my controller of the component):

```
this.currentValue = "hello universe";
```

It doesn't work, because it's an unknown variable. How can I work with the binding within my controller of the component and overwrite it etc.? In my template of the component I have no problem to access the variable, when I just work with the binding-name.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** Here I tried to show you what happens with pictures..

**Step1:** Here you can see an input, where myVariable is defined and right of the input the addon from the component, where I try to change the myVariable with a two way binding..

[image]

Step 2: Now I write in the input and overwrite the myVariable - it watches it two way and changes both (myVariable and the binding in the component):

[image]

Step 3: Now I change the binding in the controller of the component - It changes it only in the component not in the input, but I'm using two way binding (due to '=') for this:

[image]

Step 4: When I change now again the myVariable in the input, it again changes both (one way binding, but why)?:

[image]

I hope it's clear enough.

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: cannot understand if you need to change in the children scope or in the parent scope. anyway seems to be an issue of scope isolation.

Comment: @morels I try to explain it a little bit clearer, I've got the html of my web app, with it's own controller. In this controller I've got an variable "X" with a value of "Hello world". Than I've got an own component with it's own html-template and controller. This component I can implement somewhere in the html of my web app with a own tag <my-comp></my-compt>. Now this component has a binding in his controller called currentValue which I can use in the tag. Now, when the tag is in my html where I can give the variable X to my binding.. (PART 2 is comming)

Comment: @morels Than I can pass the variable X and it's value from my html to the controller of my component and show it in the template of my component. Now I would like to change it's value in the controller of my component where the binding is defined. And because of the "=" of my binding it also should watch it, so the value in my controller where the variable X is defined it also should change the value. How can I do this...Is it clearer now?

Comment: @morels please look again on the edits (code snippets): Around of my input with the ng-model myVariable I placed the component tag with the binding where I pass the myVariable throught. Than I use the ng-transclude to "merge" the template of my component with the input. In the template you can see the span, where I print out the binding value (in the picture right of the input). So now it should be clear i hope...

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS 1.5 your controller instance will be available as $ctrl in the corresponding template. Try

```
{{$ctrl.currentValue}}
```

instead. Also if you are using two way binding (due to '=') the myVariable

```
<my-component current-value="myVariable">
```

would have to be defined on the parent scope. Maybe try

```
<my-component current-value="'myVariable'">
```

initially just to see that it works..

Comment: Hi, I tried it with $ctrl it doesnt work.. I also put '' around myVariable, it just shows me a string "myVariable" not the value. What I have is, when myVariable has the value of "ABC", I can see this in the template of the component. When I overwrite the value in the controller of the component to "ABC123", in my template it's shown correct, but in the parent myVariable it's still "ABC". Than I overwrite the myVariable to "123", it updates it again in the template and shows "123" instead of "ABC123"... i use "=" for my binding, bit it just watches it one way not two...